# Why is my ReadyAPI Swagger Complience Assertion failing

Tags: swagger, openapi, ready-api

We are building a bunch of APIs and coming into a strange issue when testing them.

In our swagger file we have the following:

```
"CustomerAddress": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/StringSettable"
        },
```

And this references the following:

```
"StringSettable": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "hasValue": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "value": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
},
```

This all looks OK to us but when we run a ReadyAPI test we get the following error:

> instance type (string) does not match any allowed primitive type
> (allowed ["object"]) checked node: [/id] corresponding schema:
> [/properties/id]

This is the response payload in JSON:

```
{
         "id" : "thisisanid",
         "flat" : "Flat",
         "buildingName" : "Building",
         "houseNumber" : 11,
         "addressLine1" : "Line 1",
         "addressLine2" : "Line 2",
         "town" : "Town",
         "county" : "County",
         "locality" : "Locality",
         "district" : "District",
         "postcode" : "TE57 ING",
         "validFrom" : null,
         "country" : "United Kingdom",
         "isForeignAddress" : false,
         "isUnknownAddress" : false,
         "addressType" : 1,
         "op" : "add"
      },
```

We have tried editting the Swagger to be the following:

```
"id": {
  "type": "string",
  "nullable": true
}
```

This then passes with no issues so not 100% sure where the assertion is being tripped up on this. Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Where is ReadyAPI getting the request payload to use when executing the failing test?

Comment: How does the payload being validated look like? According to your OpenAPI schema, the `id` value should look like `{..., "id": {"hasValue": true, "value": "something"}, ... }` but the actual payload is `{..., "id": "something", ...}`. Maybe the OpenAPI schema is in fact incorrect. If the OpenAPI schema was generated from code, contact the API developers so they can fix schema generation.

Comment: @tomredfern I'm not 100% sure what you mean, the API is connecting to Dataverse and coming through an APIM Gateway back to readyAPI with the Request Payload

Comment: @Helen I have updated the question to include the payload we get back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is not working is:

*id* in the OpenAPI specification is defined as an object:

```
"StringSettable": {
    "type": "object", // <-- it's an object
    ...
}
```

but, *id* in the request payload is defined as a string:

```
{
    "id" : "thisisanid", // <-- it's a string
    ... 
}
```

In this context, the error message you are getting makes quite a lot of sense:

> instance type (string) does not match any allowed primitive type
> (allowed ["object"])

If you want to fix this problem you have two choices. The first choice you have already discovered - redefine the *id* type in the OpenAPI specification.

The second choice is to change the request payload so that the schema definition is satisfied:

```
{
    "id" : { // <-- now it's an object!
         "hasValue": true,
         "value": "thisisanid"
    },
    ... 
}
```